# We cannot make a function convex by decreasing its value

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

Let  $F:(0,1) \to [0,\infty)$ be a strictly decreasing smooth function.

*Suppose that $F$ is convex on $(0,a)$ and **strictly** concave on $(a,1)$.*

> I want to prove that we cannot make $F$ convex on $(0,1)$ by decreasing its value on $(a,1)$.

Formally, let $G:(0,1) \to \mathbb R$ be continuous, $G=F$ on $(0,a]$, and $G \le F$ on $(a,1)$.

How to prove that $G$ cannot be convex on $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F$ is strictly concave on $(a, 1)$, so that
$$
F(x) < F(a) + F'(a)(x-a)
$$
for $a < x < 1$.

If $G$ coincides with $F$ on $(0, a]$ and is $\le F$ on $[a, 1)$ then
$$
 G(x) \le F(x) < F(a) + F'(a)(x-a) = G(a) + G_-'(a)(x-a)
$$
for $a < x < 1$, so that $G$ is not convex. Here $G_-'(a)$ denotes the left-sided derivative of $G$ at $a$, which is equal to $F'(a)$.

The idea is that a concave function lies below the tangent at the graph at $x=a$, and this does not change if the function values are decreased.

---

*Remark:* The statement becomes wrong if $f$ is not required to be differentiable at $x=a$. An example is
$$
 F(x) = \begin{cases}
1-x & \text{if } 0 < x \le 1/2 \\
2x(1-x) &\text{if } 1/2 \le x < 1
\end{cases}
$$
and $G(x) = 1-x$.

Comment: Unless I made an error, the monotony of $F$ is not needed for this conclusion.

Comment: Thank you. This is a very nice answer. I also like your counter-example when $f$ is not differentiable. This is a really good example where some amount of regularity is actually needed for something to be true.